# Configure NetBeans to have spaces before, after and between function arguments

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, ide, editor

I'm saving such kind of a function in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2:

```
function ( betweenSpaces, betweenSpaces2 ) {
  obj.func( betweenSpaces, betweenSpaces2 );
}
```

I want such kind of code format, but every time I *"Source > Format"* that code with my IDE, my desired spaces are deleted. How can I set NetBeans not to delete those spaces and also to help me auto-complete every function that I'll going to create in that format? *(Thanks in advance..)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change how NetBeans formats in Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting. To change spaces formatting choose your language(Java) and Category(Spaces).

[image: NetBeansScreen]

Your probably want to check "Method Declaration" and "Method Call" in "Within Parentheses"

Comment: I can't see those checkboxes. I'm using NetBeans IDE's HTML5 & PHP Bundle. Is there a plugin that can be installed to see those options? I only have **Tabs And Indents** category.

Comment: Oh, you tagged it Java so I thought you want to format Java code. In that case choose PHP as language. Then it's almost the same.

Comment: Yes I see, I just need to choose a specific language.